# Azure WebJob runtime unable to map virtual key using MapVirtualKey (user32.dll)

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

.Net Console Application works just fine until it is uploaded as Azure WebJob to Azure website. Code to replicate:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (uint c in  new uint[] {18, 31})
        {
            var mapped = (int) MapVirtualKey(c, 1);
            Console.WriteLine($"{mapped} : {KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(mapped)}");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Expected output:

69 : E

83 : S

Actual output:

-1073741790 : None

-1073741790 : None

Not sure where to go from here. does it mean that access is denied for this api call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that the `MapVirtualKey` API is blocked by the Azure Web App sandbox. You can learn more about the sandbox on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox. See in particular this paragraph:

> For the sake of radical attack surface area reduction, the sandbox prevents almost all of the Win32k.sys APIs from being called, which practically means that most of User32/GDI32 system calls are blocked. For most applications this is not an issue since most Azure Web Apps do not require access to Windows UI functionality (they are web applications after all).

Comment: thank you! basically workaround would be to read MapVirtualKey values in usual user environment and then build a static hashmap, file, etc. and read from it during runtime for webjob